# AMP stopping video on scroll down

Tags: video, html5-video, amp-html

Is there a way to stop AMP pausing a video on scroll down,  I have a video which is in the side rail of the page but when I scroll down the page a bit the video pauses, if i scroll back up it starts again,  i want it to juts continuiously play

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove autoplay from amp-video. At least there will be no pause when scrolling.

Regards,
V

Comment: this does not answer the question, you can write it in comments when/if you have enough reputation

Comment: Thank you for the point. All the best in 2021! :)